# my onselect is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a textbox with autocomplete.
I want to display one div when the value is selected in textbox. I tried change function of jquery ui, but it is not working properly. It is only working when we click out of the textbox. I want action to be triggered when textbox got full value.

I included my code below:

index.php

```
<html>
   <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#name").autocomplete({

                        source:'search.php',
                        minLength:1,

                         change: function (event, ui) { alert("hi"); }

                    });


                });



        </script>
   </head>

   <body>

      <form method="post" action="">
          Name : <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

search.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","datadb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// ...some PHP code for database "my_db"...

// Change database to "test"
mysqli_select_db($con,"datadb");

// ...some PHP code for database "test"...


 $term=$_GET["term"];

 $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user where FirstName like '%".$term."%' GROUP by FirstName ");
 $json=array();
 if (!$query) { // add this check.
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
    while($student=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
         $json[]=array(
                    'value'=> $student["FirstName"],
                    'label'=>$student["FirstName"]
                        );
    }

 echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Comment: Have you reviewed and tried the `select` callback? http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: when exact value is selected on text box,which event can apply?

Comment: The `select` callback is triggered when a user makes a selection from autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect when you select one of your options in the autocomplete you can use the `autocompleteselect`event...

```
$("#name").autocomplete({
    source: 'search.php',
    minLength: 1
}).on('autocompleteselect',function() {
    // Do your stuff here
    alert("hi");
});
```

I hope it helps